# Black screen during change of spaces

Tags: spaces, mission-control

Using OS X 10.11.3, Mac Pro 5,1, 32GB RAM, Radeon HD 7950 (Sapphire) graphics card w/ 3GB VRAM. I have a multiple monitor setup with displays *not* having separate Spaces. Usually, when using a shortcut key to change spaces, I see a nice animation where one space slides to the left, and the new space slides in from the right.

However, once I have around six "desktops" and/or a certain number (unknown) of windows open, the animation displays a black screen when sliding the new space into place. Happens in both "directions" - the current space slides left/right, and the black screen slides in. Once the changing of the space is complete, the black goes away and the desktop reappears. [This video](https://vimeo.com/155038343) shows the phenomena at 0:15s.

Anyone encounter this and find out why this might be occurring? Never happened with the same hardware using OS X versions prior to 10.10.

Comment: A guess would be your GPU is running out of memory to be able to recalculate the transition, so it gives up & just draws once the transition is complete. Knowing what Mac & graphics would help.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, I have added some specs. I too was suspecting something either graphics card or OS related to the buffer for this animation, but I have never witnessed this with versions of OSX prior to 10.10.

Comment: hmm, OK, pretty much the same as my rig - can't say it's something I've seen. 2nd guess would be RAM struggling, trading to HD. I do see some occasional slowdown on this machine even with SSD boot drive & 64GB RAM. I'd blame Safari if I had a single vague culprit; haven't managed to find a cure though mine doesn't go so far as a black screen, it does sometimes judder across. Second swap is fine, just first is slow if i've been in one Space a long time.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a GPU issue.
[image]With OS X 10.11, this can be corrected by turning Dashboard off or setting it as an overlay (System Preferences>Mission Control).

Comment: I disagree. I have always used Dashboard as an overlay (the classic style). Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score -1):

Had that same issue because I had ScreenShade installed. Disable it, if you have it installed, and the problem will stop.